# Any CSS Sprites resources and files

Tags: css, resources, css-sprites

While there are many resources for Icons, free graphic files why can't i find any that hosts CSS Sprite images so that as a web developer that saves me time from uploading, stacking and doing nonsense stuff rather than developing the website.(I am **not** looking for css sprite generator but one that provided css sprite images as a whole that i can readily use)

Best i could find was this one :

http://www.spritecow.com/

I picked some from jQueryUi, Yahoo YUI anymore ??

#### Some More Examples:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/button/img/buttons.png

http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/images/222222_256x240_icons_icons.png

http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/preview/diagona.png

http://p.yusukekamiyamane.com/icons/preview/fugue.png

Comment: Is that really useful ? Sounds complicated in writing CSS .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Which part are u referring to as complicated? the background position thing?

Comment: Something like this? http://sourceforge.net/projects/tangoiconsprite/

Comment: @powerbuoy Exactly, that's the thing i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

I have never seen a CDN (content delivery network) for sprites, in the same way that there are CDNs for javascript libraries, etc.

I am guessing the reason is this: CSS spites are usually particular to a specific site.  They are usually clips of various images related to a specific design.  So they might not be as portable as a framework.

If you were to have several of your own sites using similar designs, you could "roll your own" sprites file and serve it from one domain to all your sites.

Comment: rolling up my own is last resort. I am just looking for sprites for action elements like search, cancel, external that are common for all websites. Fam Fam looks good but customizing size is gonna make me mad http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/previews/index_abc.png its about 1Mb

Comment: That FamFam image looks more link a collection of icons that a real spites image.  I think you're right, that you will need to customize that too.

Answer (score 1):

I am a web developer and frequent this site: http://csssprites.com/

I think it is an awesomely designed system, that automates the whole spriting task.

Comment: please note the *NOT* in the 'I am not looking for css sprite generator'